# Looking for a word that means to open an opportunity for something bad to happen

Tags: meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context

For example: "Doing many things at the same time oggies an oggy for hazards"

What's oggy?

I could say opens an opportunity for... But open an opportunity is usually used in a positive context. Also "opens the door for...", usually for good things. What's similar but has a negative connotation, meaning when used it implies something bad would happen.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the typo. To=time.

Answer (score 3):

" [asking for trouble](https://www.youridioms.com/en/idiom/to-ask-for-trouble)."

> To behave or act in a manner that will very likely result in trouble, difficulty, or danger
>
> - You shouldn't leave your children alone in the house like that or you’re asking for trouble.
> - Hey! Calm down! I know you're annoyed with your boss for making you work overtime so many times, but don't go asking for trouble!
> - Anybody who invites a complete stranger into their house is asking for trouble.
> - Those kids were just asking for trouble when they broke my house's windows.

"[Courting disaster](https://grammarist.com/phrase/court-disaster/)"

> To court disaster means to take unnecessary risks, to follow a course of action that may bring ruin, to walk a proverbial tightrope.

"[Skating on thin ice](https://www.theidioms.com/skating-on-thin-ice/)"

> to do something considered quite dangerous or risky
> to be in a situation that can get quite dangerous or risky
>
> - Sebastian using all his savings to buy blue chip stocks is definitely skating on thin ice.
> - Going into a business without carrying out proper studies is like skating on thin ice.

Answer (score 2):

**Open a can of worms**

> to create a complicated situation in which doing something to correct a problem leads to many more problems

*Our boss is reluctant to change the policy now because she doesn't want to open a can of worms.*

[Merriam-Webster]

**Pandora's box**

> something that creates a lot of new problems that you did not expect:
> Sadly, his reforms opened up a Pandora's box of domestic problems._

[Cambridge]

**Cruising for a bruising**

> (informal) Following a course of action likely to result in injury or other trouble for oneself.

*The Euroland economy has been cruising for a bruising for a while.*

[Wiktionary]

Answer (score 0):

**unfortuitously**

This works since it plays on being the opposite of a fortunate happenstance.

Usage:

> He unfortuitously left the submarine hatch open before its maiden voyage.

Comment: You should include a dictionary definition for your suggestion.